# Name of guy who teachs famous training technique for beginner drummers

Tags: learning, drums, lessons

My teacher is bad at English and he couldn't pronounce the name of the guy who teaches a famous technique that he feels will really help me.  My teacher suggested that I should  train everyday using this technique:

```
By legend
P - plant (Shaft)
C - cutting edge (tip of the drumstick)
```

On hi-hat, you use your drumstick and hit it in this sequence C-P-C-P. But you have to raise your wrist above the hi-hat when you do Cutting Edge.

Whats the name of the guy who teaches this technique?  If I know his name I can find him on-line.  In addition to this technique - he may teach others as well that myself or other beginning drummers may find helpful.

I'm not familiar with technical names...

Comment: Welcome to Music Practice and Theory SE. Unfortunately, questions that ask to identify specific techniques are off-topic. Please see here for a full list: http://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Speaking as a _user_, not as a moderator, I don't see a problem with this kind of question beyond the title needing minor improvement.

Comment: Hmmm - I'm not sure. I really can't understand what the question is asking.

Comment: @DrMayhem Check out my edits.  I think I figured out what he meant and made it more understandable.  Apparently fsi  is not a native English Speaker - but I trying to help ;)  PS: I took the liberty of trying to improve the question as well.

Comment: Yes, Im not native speaker, but the question is not only the name of the guy, but the technique too.

Comment: See my answer below and let me know if this is the technique you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a technique that appears similar to what you are asking about.  The person who originated the technique is Sanford Moeller and it is now known as the **Moeller Technique**.  It has been extensively taught by a drum teacher named Jim Chapin.

You will find many YouTube videos on using the Moeller Technique.

Here is a video of someone demonstrating the technique on the high hat with the raising of the wrist above the cymbal (as described in your question) and letting the tip of the stick fall back on it.

[Moeller Down & Up stroke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P--R5K19DYg)

He starts to demonstrate the technique you described at about 0:27 in the video.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Its not him. But I found out with another teacher I meet up.

Comment: Glad you found out.  What is name of technique?

Comment: Looking up on the internet, this teacher(he's not a drummer) doesn't know the name. But he already seen this method before.

Answer (score 1):

The name I was looking for is Gary Chester, and its not a technique, its a method of trainning on hit-hat.

Comment: fsi -- If you fleshed this out a bit more it would be a good answer.

Comment: Can you give me advice what I could improve my answer?